# How do you use an environment variable within a task group in Azure DevOps?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I have a task group that contains two tasks: one is a PowerShell script that fetches a value, and the second is an "Azure Functions" task that deploys a function. I would like to use the value from the first task in the second task (as an app setting).

My PowerShell script is of the form:

```
$result = GetSomeResult();

"##vso[task.setvariable variable=Foo;]$Result";
```

If this were called directly from a release pipeline, rather than within a task group, this would write the contents of `$result` into the pipeline variable `$Foo`. I would then be able to use it in other tasks of the pipeline (in this case, the App settings field of the Azure Functions task) as `$(Foo)`.

[image: Screenshot of Azure Functions task]

When it is in a task group, however, it does not appear to set the pipeline variable. Instead, it sets an environment variable. I can access it using another PowerShell script via `$env:Foo`, but I can't work out how to use it from a normal task.

So my question is how can I use the result of the PowerShell script in the Azure Functions task if they are both in a task group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I use the result of the PowerShell script in the Azure Functions task if they are both in a task group?

You can try the following settings in Task Group.

PowerShell task:

Script:

```
$result = GetSomeResult();
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Foo;isOutput=true]$Result"
```

[image]

Azure Function Task:

[image]

Set the Default value to the variable **Foo**: **$(foo)**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much. I tried everything I could think of, and didn't think of that :-)

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I have a similar setup, I'm setting the variable inside a PowerShell script in the exact same way (including `isOutput=true`), calling `env | sort` in the next step just to verify that it's set (it is), but I can't use `$(MyVariable)` in later steps in the task group. I also can't use `variables['MyVariable']` in a custom condition, as it's always the initial value that was passed into the task group, not the value that I set it to in the PowerShell script.